# Change frame not by origin

Tags: ios, frame

I have an draggable UIImageView that at some point changes to another UIImageView frame. Problem is I need to make the transformation using the same clicked point in the first UIImageView. I simply do this:

```
_firstImageView.frameSize = _secondImageView.frameSize;
```

But the frame changes from the _firstImageView origin. I need to do the transformation from the point I clicked inside the _firstImageView:

```
CGPoint clickedPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
```

I had tried the layer.anchorPoint but that makes the imageView disappear, don't know why (I did first a conversionPoint from self.view to the _firstImageView reference system)

EDIT e.g for better explanation of problem:

I have a uiimage1 frame with height of 100. And another with 50.
If I click in the point (y=90) of uiimage1 and start dragging, there's an test intersection that I make and if intersects it changes that UIImage1 to the frame of UIImage2. But since the click was on y=90 and UIImage2 only has max y-height of 50, it changes the frame size by the UIImage1 origin. I continue dragging with the click point outside the new frame (that is only y-height=50 and point click is y=90). My question is: Can I change the frame not by its origins but by that point clicked position?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be more clear?

Comment: Do you want that firstimageview doesn't change origin but only has width and height same as secondimageview?

Answer (score 0):

```
+(CGRect)getUpdatedFrame:(CGRect)frame byChangingCenterTo:(CGPoint)newCenter
{
    float width = frame.size.width;
    float height = frame.size.height;
    return CGRectMake(newCenter.x-width/2, newCenter.y-height/2, width, height);
}

+(CGPoint)centerForRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return CGPointMake( rect.origin.x+rect.size.width/2 , rect.origin.y+rect.size.height/2 );
}
```

Comment: above two methods can help you